# iCal what is the difference between these two rrules?

Tags: icalendar

The last work day of the month

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1
```

‘PAY DAY’ – the last week day in the month!

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=-1MO,-1TU,-1WE,-1TH,-1FR;BYSETPOS=-1
```

I'm having trouble with the difference between these two. I believe they may be equal, are they?

Comment: If they are equal, why should that constitute "trouble"? Is it evil that there might be more than one way to express something?

Comment: "I believe they may be equal". The trouble is not being sure.

Answer (score 2):

These two exactly same.

> FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1

Here we collect **ALL** the "MO,TU,WE,TH,FR" of a month. Lets call this set A. Then we select the last occurrence from this set.

> RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=-1MO,-1TU,-1WE,-1TH,-1FR;BYSETPOS=-1

Here we collect **THE LAST** "MO,TU,WE,TH,FR" each of a month. Lets call this set B. Then we select the last occurrence from this set.

As you can see, set A is a superset of set B. Whatever elements are in set B will always be in set A.

Hence they are the same.